# Connection to http://krono.act.uji.es refused

Tags: java, connection, liferay-6, jena

I am trying to read an ontology OWL file using the Jena Framework with a piece of code that starts like this:

```
OntDocumentManager mgr = new OntDocumentManager();
OntModelSpec s1 = new OntModelSpec(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM);
s1.setDocumentManager(mgr);
OntModel m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(s1, null);

InputStream in = FileManager.get().open("wine.owl");

if (in == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("File: " + inputFileName + " not found");
}

m.read(in, "");
m.read("food.owl");
```

I am getting a bunch of Warnings (HttpHostConnectionException, ConnectionException). It apparently occurs when it parses/connects to through the ENTITY uri in the owl file, "An error occurred while attempting to read from http://krono.act.uji.es/Links/ontologies/food.owl", "Connection to http://krono.act.uji.es refused" and a similar one for wine.owl. The code runs with a lot (around a 100) of such connection warnings but I need to resolve them to include the code into Liferay for a portlet. So any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT:** Tried the work-arounds but I have now discovered that the problem lies with even simple Java programs connecting to any URL and retrieving information from them. Are there any special Network configurations for java which I should verify? The proxy within eclipse is also correct by the way.

Comment: `Connection refused` speaks for itself, more or less. It could be due to a port not being open, or a firewall, for example.

Comment: Well I hope you aren't DOSing them? Do you have rate limiting in place?

Comment: @Hassan: Not really. And proxy setting for eclipse isn't used for your Java app. so it has nothing to do with that. It probably has nothing to do with Java. Try executing traceroute and curl etc. to see if it's a network issue. If that has similar problems, you probably want to open a new question in superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

Are you hitting them from your production code naively on each request? If so you shouldn't do that unless you have permission from them to do so. Without permission that may well consitute a DOS attack against them. In fact it's possible that the `Connection Refused` is due to their servers being overloaded or their counter measures.

If you are allowed to use their resources, why can't you download them and host them yourself? If you are worried about the resource going stale, you could periodically crawl and update them.

**EDIT** (response to comment): Sorry I didn't realize your use case fully. In that case, I think a proxy is indeed a good idea. You could setup a Squid proxy with an appropriate write expirely and rate limit (see http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/DelayPools).

Alternatively you can do this your self using e.g. Guava's Cache and RateLimiter. Something like 2 requests per second is probably OK. However, especially if you are having trouble reaching their servers, it might be nice if you contact them and ask what kind of load is acceptable.

Comment: I am trying to learn the capabilities of the Jena Framework so was practicing on a widely available OWL file on the internet. No DOSing intended. So a local version of the file worked on independent of the updates from the uri should not cause such errors, right? Is it possible to edit the file to remove the references to the 'ENTITTY' url? Or I have been suggested it could do something with the proxy set up on eclipse. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @Hassan: Added a response, HTH

Comment: @Hassan If you use a local copy of the file, then you can configure Jena to use that local copy when it sees the URI for the remote file.